# Finalizing a JRuby application

Tags: ruby, deployment, compilation, jruby

So I have created an application in JRuby for the first time. Now I'm having trouble to understand how to finalize the application, ie. how to provide a `.jar` file that can be executed by the end user.

I'm aware of compiling to a `.class` file which can be invoked via the command line, but that's not very user friendly.

How do I provide an easy access to my application written in JRuby to an end user?

Comment: https://github.com/jruby/jruby/wiki/StandaloneJarsAndClasses

Comment: Thank you. Seeing that I'm still a beginner, is there a more concrete guide? Something like a walkthrough?

Comment: There are step by step instructions on that page, although without knowing any specifics about your app it's difficult to provide further advice.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I provide an easy access to my application written in JRuby to
>   an end user?

You can try to install the rawr gem and see if you can get that to work.

**1**) To create all the necessary rawr files for your project(this is after you install the rawr gem):

```
~/jruby_programs$ mkdir proj1
~/jruby_programs$ cd proj1
~/jruby_programs/proj1$ rawr install
```

Then you get a bunch of output.  That creates this directory structure:

```
../proj1
├── Rakefile
├── build_configuration.rb
├── lib
│   └── java
│       └── jruby-complete.jar
└── src
    └── org
        └── monkeybars
            └── rawr
                ├── Main.java
                └── Path.java
```

**2**) Put your source code in the src/ directory, e.g.

```
./src
├── hello_jruby.rb
└── org/



#hello_jruby.rb

puts 'hello'

require 'java'
java_import 'java.util.TreeSet'

set = TreeSet.new
set.add "foo"
set.add "Bar"
set.add "baz"

set.each do |v|
  puts "value: #{v}"
end
```

**3**) Create the jar file:

```
~/jruby_programs/proj1$ rake rawr:jar
```

I initially used `rake rawr:base_jar` because that is what the rawr docs indicate you should do, but that wouldn't work for me.  When I executed the jar file(see next step), I kept getting the error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/jruby/RubyInstanceConfig  at
>   org.monkeybars.rawr.Main.main(Main.java:21) Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jruby.RubyInstanceConfig

**4**) Execute the jar file:

```
~/jruby_programs/proj1$ java -jar package/jar/proj1.jar
```

This is my output:

```
Add 'src/' to $:
hello
value: Bar
value: baz
value: foo
```

Unfortuantely, I don't know how to get rid of that first line.  `$:` is a ruby global variable whose synonym is `$LOAD_PATH`.  Adding the following to the top of `hello_jruby.rb` didn't work:

```
$LOAD_PATH << '/src'
```

Here are the tweaks I had to make to the build_configurationl.rb file(you only have to uncomment sections if the defaults don't work for you):

```
# Generated by Rawr version 1.7.0
configuration do |c|
    # The name for your resulting application file (e.g., if the project_name is 'foo' then you'll get foo.jar, foo.exe, etc.)
    # default value: "proj1"
    #
    #c.project_name = "proj1"

    # Undocumented option 'output_dir'
    # default value: "package"
    #
    #c.output_dir = "package"

    # The type of executable to create (console or gui)
    # default value: "gui"
    #
    c.executable_type = "console"

    # The main ruby file to invoke, minus the .rb extension
    # default value: "main"
    #
    c.main_ruby_file = 'hello_jruby'

    # The fully-qualified name of the main Java file used to initiate the application.
    # default value: "org.monkeybars.rawr.Main"
    #
    #c.main_java_file = "org.monkeybars.rawr.Main"

    # A list of directories where source files reside
    # default value: ["src"]
    #
    #c.source_dirs = ["src"]

    # A list of regexps of files to exclude
    # default value: []
    #
    #c.source_exclude_filter = []

    # The base directory that holds Mirah files, or subdirectories with Mirah files.
    # default value: "src"
    #
    #c.mirah_source_root = "src"

    # Whether Ruby source files should be compiled into .class files. Setting this to true currently breaks packaging
    # default value: false
    #
    #c.compile_ruby_files = false

    # A list of individual Java library files to include.
    # default value: []
    #
    #c.java_lib_files = []

    # A list of directories for rawr to include . All files in the given directories get bundled up.
    # default value: ["lib/java"]
    #
    #c.java_lib_dirs = ["lib/java"]

    # A list of files that will be copied into the `<output_dir>/jar` folder.  Note that the files maintain their directory path when copied. 
    # default value: []
    #
    #c.files_to_copy = []

    # Undocumented option 'source_jvm_version'
    # default value: 1.7
    #
    c.source_jvm_version = 1.6

    # Undocumented option 'target_jvm_version'
    # default value: 1.7
    #
    c.target_jvm_version = 1.6

    # Undocumented option 'jvm_arguments'
    # default value: ""
    #
    #c.jvm_arguments = ""

    # Undocumented option 'java_library_path'
    # default value: ""
    #
    #c.java_library_path = ""

    # Undocumented option 'extra_user_jars'
    # default value: {}
    #
    #c.extra_user_jars[:data] = { :directory => 'data/images/png',
    #                             :location_in_jar => 'images',
    #                             :exclude => /*.bak$/ }

    # Undocumented option 'verbose'
    # default value: false
    #
    #c.verbose = false

    # Undocumented option 'mac_do_not_generate_plist'
    # default value: false
    #
    #c.mac_do_not_generate_plist = false

    # working directory specified in plist file
    # default value: "$APP_PACKAGE"
    #
    #c.mac_plist_working_directory = "$APP_PACKAGE"

    # Undocumented option 'mac_icon_path'
    # default value: nil
    #
    #c.mac_icon_path = nil

    # Undocumented option 'windows_icon_path'
    # default value: nil
    #
    #c.windows_icon_path = nil

end
```